# Unable to view custom component on VF page due to Unauthorized error 401

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites

After creating a custom component and adding it into lightning app and using that App in VF page, trying to access VF page using sites but getting the error as shown in the screenshot. Please help with any possible solution. I've tried checking the public access settings but couldn't find the issue.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Few things you can check

1. If your lightning components displays outside VF page, within SF
2. Have you implemented required interface

```
<aura:application extends="ltng:outApp" implements="ltng:allowGuestAccess" access="GLOBAL">
    <aura:dependency resource="c:caseSearchComponent"/>
</aura:application>
```